# How to find whether a particular string has unicode characters (esp. Double Byte characters)

Tags: javascript, unicode, double-byte

To be more precise, I need to know whether (and if possible, how) I can find whether a given string has double byte characters or not. Basically, I need to open a pop-up to display a given text which can contain double byte characters, like Chinese or Japanese. In this case, we need to adjust the window size than it would be for English or ASCII.
Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Well, I expected this to work. But it didn't work in IE. I guess some layout problems. Anyways, since the code to compute the text-to-be-shown length and height/width was already there, I went ahead with the code that just finds whether there is a double byte character or not. And this solved.

Comment: With HTML5, you can use the context of a Canvas element (`var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')`) to obtain the width text metric. `var text_width = ctx.measureText(text).width;` I'm not sure how well this method works with unicode characters, and its a shame that all the `measureText` method currently returns is width.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

JavaScript holds text internally as UCS-2, which can encode a fairly extensive subset of Unicode.

But that's not really germane to your question.  One solution might be to loop through the string and examine the character codes at each position:

```
function isDoubleByte(str) {
    for (var i = 0, n = str.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (str.charCodeAt( i ) > 255) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This might not be as fast as you would like.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript, but don't you mean UTF-16?  There is no such thing as UCS-16; there were UCS-x encoding forms, now obsolete, in the ISO/IEC 10646 standard that's equivalent to Unicode.  UCS-2 used exactly two bytes and could thus represent the first 2^16 Unicode characters.  UTF-16, on the contrary, uses 16-bit units, but not necessarily a single one of those.  All Unicode characters can be represented as UTF-16 byte sequences.

Answer (score 53):

I used mikesamuel answer on this one. However I noticed perhaps because of this form that there should only be one escape slash before the `u`, e.g. `\u` and not `\\u` to make this work correctly.

```
function containsNonLatinCodepoints(s) {
    return /[^\u0000-\u00ff]/.test(s);
}
```

Works for me :)

Comment: Your function is much better than the ticked answer, regex is always better

Comment: this works for me too, using regrex is better in performance than using a loop as well.

Answer (score 16):

I have benchmarked the two functions in the top answers and thought I would share the results. Here is the test code I used:

```
const text1 = `The Chinese Wikipedia was established along with 12 other Wikipedias in May 2001. 中文維基百科的副標題是「海納百川，有容乃大」，這是中国的清朝政治家林则徐（1785年－1850年）於1839年為`;

const regex = /[^\u0000-\u00ff]/; // Small performance gain from pre-compiling the regex
function containsNonLatinCodepoints(s) {
    return regex.test(s);
}

function isDoubleByte(str) {
    for (var i = 0, n = str.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (str.charCodeAt( i ) > 255) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}

function benchmark(fn, str) {
    let startTime = new Date();
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        fn(str);
    }   
    let endTime = new Date();

    return endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
}

console.info('isDoubleByte => ' + benchmark(isDoubleByte, text1));
console.info('containsNonLatinCodepoints => ' + benchmark(containsNonLatinCodepoints, text1));
```

When running this I got:

```
isDoubleByte => 2421
containsNonLatinCodepoints => 868
```

So for this particular string the regex solution is about 3 times faster.

However note that for a string where the first character is unicode, `isDoubleByte()` returns right away and so is much faster than the regex (which still has the overhead of the regular expression).

For instance for the string `中国`, I got these results:

```
isDoubleByte => 51
containsNonLatinCodepoints => 288
```

To get the best of both world, it's probably better to combine both:

```
var regex = /[^\u0000-\u00ff]/; // Small performance gain from pre-compiling the regex
function containsDoubleByte(str) {
    if (!str.length) return false;
    if (str.charCodeAt(0) > 255) return true;
    return regex.test(str);
}
```

In that case, if the first character is Chinese (which is likely if the whole text is Chinese), the function will be fast and return right away. If not, it will run the regex, which is still faster than checking each character individually.

Answer (score 7):

Here is benchmark test: http://jsben.ch/NKjKd

This is much faster:

```
function containsNonLatinCodepoints(s) {
    return /[^\u0000-\u00ff]/.test(s);
}
```

than this:

```
function isDoubleByte(str) {
    for (var i = 0, n = str.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (str.charCodeAt( i ) > 255) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! So many thanks! It helped in making a crypto library sodium free

Comment: @jolly Sodium-free?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, all of the characters are Unicode, at least from the Javascript engine's perspective.

Unfortunately, the mere presence of characters in a particular Unicode range won't be enough to determine you need more space. There are a number of characters which take up roughly the same amount of space as other characters which have Unicode codepoints well above the ASCII range. Typographic quotes, characters with diacritics, certain punctuation symbols, and various currency symbols are outside of the low ASCII range and are allocated in quite disparate places on the Unicode basic multilingual plane.

Generally, projects that I've worked on elect to provide extra space for all languages, or sometimes use javascript to determine whether a window with auto-scrollbar css attributes actually has content with a height which would trigger a scrollbar or not.

If detecting the presence of, or count of, CJK characters will be adequate to determine you need a bit of extra space, you could construct a regex using the following ranges:
[\u3300-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff], and use that to extract a count of the number of characters that match. (This is a little excessively coarse, and misses all the non-BMP cases, probably excludes some other relevant ranges, and most likely includes some irrelevant characters, but it's a starting point).

Again, you're only going to be able to manage a rough heuristic without something along the lines of a full text rendering engine, because what you really want is something like GDI's MeasureString (or any other text rendering engine's equivalent). It's been a while since I've done so, but I think the closest HTML/DOM equivalent is setting a width on a div and requesting the height (cut and paste reuse, so apologies if this contains errors):

```
o = document.getElementById("test");

document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(o,"").getPropertyValue("height"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the window resize itself based on the runtime height/width?

Run something like this in your pop-up:

```
window.resizeTo(document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight);
```

Comment: Something like this should work in non-pathological cases; of course you'd need to make sure you're not exceeding the available screen space, or at least assume reasonable limits.