# Javascript regex character set restriction related query

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a JavaScript RegEx which is mentioned below:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*([-_.])).+$
```

This accepts only that text which has at least 1: uppercase letter, lowercase letter, number & a special symbol from .-_.

Now assume I supply `User-123` as the user id which confirms to the above RegEx & I use the onscreen keyboard to type in a character from Finnish language, which results in `User-123Ã`.

The RegEx being fulfilled, the text is accepted by my JavaScript code, but I want it to only accept Alphanumeric input in English, and nothing else.

How should I enhance this RegEx to do so?

Comment: Check the `.+$` - it allows all letters. You can use `[\w.-]+$` instead to restrict to the characters you require in the lookaheads.

Comment: Maybe it will be clearer to have a regex of the sort: `[^A-Za-z\d_.-]` and throw an error if that matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew, please start writing answers in the answers section. This is not the first time I wasted 2+ minutes reading a question that you have already answered in the comments.

Comment: ndn - please post what you think is correct - I do not know what the real answer is.

Comment: I do not think just posting "Use `my_cool_code_or_regex`" is a valid answer. That is why I did not post my comment. Writing an answer takes time, and I do not always have lots of it.

Answer (score 1):

This string "User-123Ã" have contain Unicode "Ã" not alphabets, so how can identify js code,

```
[Code]  [Glyph] [Decimal]   [HTML]      Description                         [#]
U+00C3  Ã       &#195;      &Atilde;    Latin Capital letter A with tilde   0131
```

Try this link also,
[How to find whether a particular string has unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147824/how-to-find-whether-a-particular-string-has-unicode-characters-esp-double-byte)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will solve the issue, but in most cases when you want to restrict the *input* itself to some characters, your *consuming* pattern should only match those characters you allow. The lookahead restrictions just require or forbid certain characters to appear certain number of times at certain positions, but what you match in the consuming part is crucial.

`.+$` allows all letters. Replace it with `[\w.-]+$` (`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) instead to restrict to the characters you require in the lookaheads.